# Would rendering After Effects project in Premiere Pro decrease quality?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, video-quality, adobe-media-encoder

I have created a motion logo using After Effects. Now, I want to render it in **H.264** or **MP4** format. Now, there are **3** ways for it:
1. Using Media Encoder
2. Export as Premiere Pro Project in After Effects and Use it in Premiere Pro
3. Save the Project as After Effects project and Import it in Premeire Pro

Now, what I want to ask is about quality of the video. Would all ways yield same quality for same format? Or There's difference between them in terms of quality? If yes, what would be best?

My **2**nd question is: I'm making a short video like a Movie trailer. I would create the scenes in **Pr** and the Motion Logo (which I've already created in After effects) in **Ae**. In what way should I render them (I need **MP4** video)? Import the Motion Logo project in Premiere Pro and render both Logo and Video **OR** both Video scenes and Logo in Media encoder?

NOTE: I'm asking these questions in terms of quality of Motion Logo and Video scenes, not in terms of ease of usage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing from AE using dynamic linking and rendering in Premiere or Media Encoder will yield the same quality, but it does give you a little less control over the render settings.

While in AE you can choose whether to render with frame blending , motion blur, draft settings and so on, Premiere will always render your AE comp with the current settings. So when you're setting up your final render in Premiere, make sure you jump over to AE and turn on motion blur and frame blending and check that all your layers are rendering at full quality, not draft. Most of the time you *won't* want these on while you're editing because they slow down the preview so much.

As far as quality goes I believe that it uses the same render engine, so don't obsess about it. In fact re-encoding from an After Effects render is probably more lossy than importing using dynamic linking, because of the two compression stages. **But you will never *ever* notice the difference one way or the other**, trust me. Any miniscule losses due to things like quantisation errors and so on are going to pale into insignificance with quality lost in the compression to MP4.

Use the way that makes it much easier for you. For me that's importing via dynamic linking, allowing me to change things in the AE project without re-rendering all the time and having great big render files all over the place.

Comment: I created the images for the Motion logo in Illustrator. But after rendering I don't see the logo as cool and perfect as it was in Illustrator and saved image as PNG of that logo. Can there be some settings problems? Or I would always lose the quality after rendering?

Comment: Did you turn on continuous rasterisation for the vector layers? Have you tried comparing renders done in AE vs Premiere?

Comment: For experiement, I created a simple text in After effects and rendered it as QuickTime with RGB and RGB+Alpha settings. Then I saved the project as Aep. Then imported in Pr and when rendered it gave me Quality say X. And finally, I rendered the same text in After effects as Lossless AVI format and then imported in Pr and rendered with original settings and it gave me quality say Y. Now, when I compared them, the Quality was like this: .mov (RGB) > .mov (+Alpha) > Y > X. What can be the issue. I don't understand. I think same is happening with my original logo created using Ai.

Comment: The RGB mov and the RGBA mov shouldn't vary in quality if they're using the same codec and quality settings, and if you're using a lossless quicktime codec it should be identical to the lossless AVI (after all, that's what lossless means). Either your render settings are wonky, or something else is going on. When you compare the quality are you just looking at the Premiere preview? Premiere often drops quality a lot during playback.

Comment: No. the quality after rendering in Premiere Pro to MP4.

Comment: I request you to answer this question as well. It's totally related to this problem and I've described it in a better way. Here's it: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19288/why-do-i-get-different-qualities-of-video-in-different-adobe-products